# Get Window Handle (HWND) in chrome extension

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension which uses chrome's native messaging api to communicate to a host application. The host application is written in C++. Now my host application requires the Window Handle HWND of the chrome tab in which my extension is currently active.

Is there a way to do this? I can't use any of the NPAPI solutions.

I have gone through the documentation of the chrome extensions there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

I have seen this answer: [Get Window Handle of Chrome Tab from Within Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472708/get-window-handle-of-chrome-tab-from-within-extension)

But the above answer doesn't explain things clearly. Is it asking for matching the title of windows by iterating through all the windows? How do I do this? What if multiple tabs have the same title? Can Tab Id or window Id be used in some way?

Comment: Well, tabs don't have their own hwnd, only the window has as you can see in `spyxx`. What are you planning to do in your native host app with the hwnd?

Comment: @wOxxOm: Spy++ shows different hwnds for different tabs. Keep in mind this question is related to chrome not firefox.

Comment: @wOxxOm: I am using the find window option in Spy++ and dragging the finder tool to the different tabs - gives me different handles.

Comment: Rendering something in the tab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95450/discussion-between-woxxom-and-lesnar).

Comment: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-extensions/c/le_KmOrmDpI

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty hack I am using
I would set the browser title to something unique and then I would get the window/process by window title.

c#

```
string title = $"getting the window handle({Rnd(1, 999999999)})...";
JSExecute($"document.title = '{title}';");
process = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MainWindowTitle.Contains(title));
```